# Getting Resources Not found exception on Nexus 5

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0, nexus-5

Today I decided to test my application on my old phone, the Nexus 5. I normally code and test on my Nexus 6 and everything works perfect. However, when I attempted to run the app on my Nexus 5 I get this `Resources.NotFoundException` in my login screen onCreate:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBaEn.jpg)

After doing some digging on Stackoverflow I believe the error might have something to do with the Nexus 5's default layout configuration. But, even after reading countless threads I still don't know where to start.

Here are some more screenshots that may be helpful:

[onCreate Where error is thrown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dD0Sz.jpg)

[My res files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K27pw.jpg)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. My Nexus 5 is running API 23, my nexus 6 is running 25. Created new drawable folder in res called "drawable-v23" and pasted all my drawables into it.

Also did this with my layout folder

Comment: I get the same error reported through crashlytics, *all* of them by Nexus 5X devices. Using `drawable-v23` is not a good solution, because I get those errors for API27 and API30 as well. Still looking for a viable solution.